# Show UITabBar on UIViewControllers that are not part of the UITabBar?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS app written in Swift with `UITabBarController` with 5 `UIViewControllers`. Now, I have a bunch of `UIViewControllers` that are not part of the `UITabBarController`. I'd like to be able to show that same tabbar but I have no idea how to do that. Any clue?

More details: This is one of the View Controllers that the tabbar has. I use storyboard references and split my view controllers into separate more manageable storyboards.

So, the big picture:

[image]

There's no initial ViewController since I use storyboardId to get to the initial Navigation Controller. From there we have a ViewController embedded in the same Navigation controller. In that ViewController, there are 2 Container views - one of the size of the bottom ViewController that contains the "hamburger" button that toggles the other Container View which has an embedded UITableView in. When a specific cell is selected it should go to Profile ViewController that's not even in the same storyboard. The segue is set to be Push. Either way, doesn't show the UITabBar on the Profile ViewController

[image]

Comment: How are you presenting/showing the other `UIViewController`s? If they are being pushed on to a `UINavigationController` that's part of the `UITabBarController` hierarchy then the tab bar should be visible.

Comment: Well, it depends but I have my entire project split into many Storyboards and connected via storyboard references. So, the segue could be whatever I make it to be I think

Comment: Well, as I said, if for example one of your `UITabBarController` has a `UINavigationController` as one of it's items whenever you push a new `UIViewController` on it's stack the tab bar stays in place. If you'd modally present it the tab bar will be hidden.

Comment: @MihaiFratu I think I'm doing something wrong because it's not working. I've added more details and some screenshots in the post itself. Can you please take a look at that?

Answer (score 0):

how you doing? 
I don't know if I understood, but you are trying to show tabbar after going to another screen, right? If the answer is 'yes', try to change your segue to `show(e.g. push)`.

-----Edit-----

You can do with two ways:

1. Presenting Modally -> using Current Context

[image]

2. Use `push(e.g.)` with a `navigation view controller`, you can also hide the navigation bar if you go to `Navigation controller -> Attributes inspector -> Navigation Controller -> Uncheck Shows Navigation Bar`

[image]

Hope now it works!
Best regards

Comment: You understood me correctly, yes. But the segue is already set to `Show (e.g. push)` and it's not working.

Comment: Check if in your ViewController is check the option "hide Bottom Bar on push"

Comment: Yes, it is checked

Comment: If "hide Bottom Bar on push" is checked try to uncheck

Comment: It's unchecked by default.

Comment: Try to modify 'bottom bar' to 'translucent tab bar' in "simulated metrics" of your view controller

Comment: Sadly, no change even after that

Comment: First option worked, but then in the `ProfileViewController` the home Tab bar icon is selected (and it shouldn't be because this is not the home tab bar) and when you go around and click through the rest of the tabs and go back to the first one (home) it stays on the same `ProfileViewController` instead of going back to the first original tab bar view controller. If I can fix that, I think this would work

Comment: Why don't you use view did disappear to go back to the first screen?